# Fabricjs ignore transparent objects inside group

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I would like to know if it's possible to 'ignore' transparent objects.
The idea is that if I draw over another object, the drawing path will group with the underlying object (this works). Now I want the free drawing path only visible inside the object itself. See picture below for reference.

What I have:
https://pasteboard.co/IqSuu4Y.png

What I would like to have:
https://pasteboard.co/IqSwxfv.png

I was thinking that the 'perPixelTargetFind' options could step in, but I can't get it to work.